# Is there a methodology or color choice that allows an app's UI to be more visible in outdoor conditions?

Tags: mobile, physical, color-blindness, light

I saw this question on another Q&A website and was wondering the same. This is a question that resurfaces from time to time, even on this website, where there are several questions with no answer, or at least not a definitive one.

So, the question is: **is there a color palette, technique, or method I can use under challenging visual conditions, such as sun glare?**

**Note:** I am aware of the techniques that partially help overcome the problem, as well as some external tools like anti-glare screens. However, with the technology available in 2024, there might be solutions that effectively work well through native implementations.

Comment: actually yes, feel free to mark this as duplicate :)